# Laravel 5.4 Multiple EMail Drivers Amazon SES and Mailtrap

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, swiftmailer

Throughout my Laravel 5.4 codebase, I am using Amazon SES to send email:

```
Mail::to('myemail@example.com')->send(new App\Mail\MyEmailClass);
```

Not a problem. Except I am working in a team, and I test email a lot. I want to use Mailtrap.io for testing emails rather than spamming my own account(s).

To configure Mailtrap with PHP/Laravel, I am required to use the SMTP driver and Mailtrap SMTP host, and port:

```
return array(
  "driver" => "smtp",
  "host" => "smtp.mailtrap.io",
  "port" => 2525,
);
```

My driver is currently set to use SES.

How can I use multiple drivers: SES and Mailtrap?

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you still facing this problem...Instead of you change "mail.php" inside the "config" directory, why not considering insert this in ".env" file entering the following parameters:

```
MAIL_DRIVER = smtp
MAIL_HOST = smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT = 465
MAIL_USERNAME = "get this on mailtrap settings"
MAIL_PASSWORD = "get this on mailtrap settings"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION =
```